# Facebook GraphAPI - Get a list of groups a user belongs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get the list a groups a user belong with Facebook Graph API.
According to the documentation, I tried this :

```
GET /me/groups
```

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/)

It requires the `user_managed_groups` privillege, but it only shows groups that the user manage. I would like all groups the user belongs.

Is it possible ? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to use the `user_groups` permission for that, but that permission is deprecated and will be removed soon: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Meaning, it is not possible, i´m afraid.

Comment: So now way to tell if someone belongs to a group ? Oo

Comment: nope, not anymore. that permission was doomed to get removed, it was not even possible to get it approved in the review process in the last months.